# How can i keep the transform height while it's moving?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
bool flying = false; // shows when FlyTo is running
                         // coroutine that moves to the specified point:
    IEnumerator FlyTo(Vector3 targetPos)
    {
        flying = true; // flying is true while moving to the target
        Vector3 startPos = transform.position;
        Vector3 dir = targetPos - startPos;
        float distTotal = dir.magnitude;
        dir /= distTotal; // normalize vector dir
                          // calculate accDist even for short distances
        float accDist = Mathf.Min(accDistance, distTotal / 2);
        do
        {
            float dist1 = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, startPos);
            float dist2 = distTotal - dist1;
            float speed = maxVel; // assume cruise speed
            if (dist1 < accDist)
            { // but if in acceleration range...
              // accelerate from startVel to maxVel
                speed = Mathf.Lerp(startVel, maxVel, dist1 / accDist);
            }
            else
            if (dist2 < accDist)
            { // or in deceleration range...
              // fall from maxVel to stopVel
                speed = Mathf.Lerp(stopVel, maxVel, dist2 / accDist);
            }
            // move according to current speed:
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPos, speed * Time.deltaTime);
            yield return 0; // let Unity breathe till next frame
        } while (transform.position != targetPos); // finish when target reached
        flying = false; // shows that flight has finished
    }
```

The problem is if for example the transform is at height 200 in the start when it's getting to the targetPos it's in height 0.

But i want it to get to the targetPos above it in the same height not on height 0. It does not matter what it will do when it's getting to the targetPos but what i want is that it will get there at the same height level.

This is the full script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ControlShip : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float maxVel = 30; // cruise speed
    public float startVel = 5; // speed at the starting point
    public float stopVel = 0.5f; // speed at the destination
    public float accDistance = 20; // acceleration/deceleration distance
    public float factor = 0.25f; // max inclination
    public float turnSpeed = 0.8f; // speed to turn/bank in the target direction
    Vector3 lastPos; // used to calculate current velocity
    Transform baseTarget;
    private Rigidbody _rigidbody;

    void Start()
    {
        _rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        baseTarget = GameObject.Find("Base").transform;
        lastPos = transform.position;
        StartCoroutine(Fly()); // demo routine
    }
    // calculate bank/turn rotation at Update
    void Update()
    {
        // calculate the displacement since last frame:
        Vector3 dir = transform.position - lastPos;
        lastPos = transform.position; // update lastPos
        float dist = dir.magnitude;
        if (dist > 0.001f)
        { // if moved at least 0.001...
            dir /= dist; // normalize dir...
            float vel = dist / Time.deltaTime; // and calculate current velocity
                                               // bank in the direction of movement according to velocity
            Quaternion bankRot = Quaternion.LookRotation(dir + factor * Vector3.down * vel / maxVel);

            Vector3 rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, bankRot, turnSpeed * Time.deltaTime).eulerAngles;
            rotation.x = 0;
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(rotation);
        }
    }

    bool flying = false; // shows when FlyTo is running
                         // coroutine that moves to the specified point:
    IEnumerator FlyTo(Vector3 targetPos)
    {
        flying = true; // flying is true while moving to the target
        Vector3 startPos = transform.position;
        Vector3 dir = targetPos - startPos;
        float distTotal = dir.magnitude;
        dir /= distTotal; // normalize vector dir
                          // calculate accDist even for short distances
        float accDist = Mathf.Min(accDistance, distTotal / 2);
        do
        {
            float dist1 = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, startPos);
            float dist2 = distTotal - dist1;
            float speed = maxVel; // assume cruise speed
            if (dist1 < accDist)
            { // but if in acceleration range...
              // accelerate from startVel to maxVel
                speed = Mathf.Lerp(startVel, maxVel, dist1 / accDist);
            }
            else
            if (dist2 < accDist)
            { // or in deceleration range...
              // fall from maxVel to stopVel
                speed = Mathf.Lerp(stopVel, maxVel, dist2 / accDist);
            }
            // move according to current speed:

            Vector3 pos = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPos, speed * Time.deltaTime);
            pos.y = lastPos.y;
            transform.position = pos;
            yield return 0; // let Unity breathe till next frame
        } while (transform.position != targetPos); // finish when target reached
        flying = false; // shows that flight has finished        
    }
    // example routine: fly to 3 different points in sequence
    IEnumerator Fly()
    {
        Vector3 p0 = baseTarget.position;

        while (true)
        {
            StartCoroutine(FlyTo(p0));
            while (flying)
            {
                yield return 0;
            }
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.name == "Base")
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: By the way, you don't need to do this: `float distTotal = dir.magnitude; dir /= distTotal; // normalize vector dir`, `dir.normalize()` already exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in my comments, don't update the position twice, this will cause an overhead, easily avoidable by changing the Target's Y coordinate BEFORE the loop.

```
 IEnumerator FlyTo(Vector3 targetPos)
    {
        flying = true; // flying is true while moving to the target
        Vector3 startPos = transform.position;

        //Insert this line right here.
        targetPos.y = startPos.y;
        Vector3 dir = targetPos - startPos;
        //The rest of your code remains the same...
```

Find this line, inside your DO, near the end and remove it

```
       Vector3 pos = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPos, speed * Time.deltaTime);
    //pos.y = lastPos.y; ~ REMOVE THIS LINE~
```

assuming that Y is the height axis, maybe its actually Z axis,try it out.

Comment: I got it working by this: Vector3 pos = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPos, speed * Time.deltaTime);
            pos.y = lastPos.y;
            transform.position = pos; The variable lastPos is already have the transform start position.  Wanted to post it as a solution.

Comment: Don't do like that, you are updating the position twice, so the engine has to recalculate it's position for collision and stuff like that. Theres some overhead there, fix the Y coordinate BEFORE the loop. As i answered. But yes, your solution would work too.

Comment: Should i put your solution code inside the do ? Or in the Start() ? flying is already set to true before the do/while.  And in the Start() i have a variable lastPos that hold the transform.position at the start.

Comment: I update my question added also the full script to make it more clear. The same way i did with the position i also did before it with the rotation. Same idea. The part with the rotation i did in the bottom of the Update(). Do i need then to change both places for rotation and position ? If you can show me how to do it. Thanks.

Comment: Working great. Could you please look for second on the rotation part i mentioned ? Inside the Update() at the bottom of the Update() i did: Vector3 rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, bankRot, turnSpeed * Time.deltaTime).eulerAngles;
            rotation.x = 0;
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(rotation); Should i change it too ?

Comment: The rotation does not suffer from the same problem, since you only update the transform once, so, good stuff;